# asprint memory leak need help understand where leak is coming from and possible fixes

Tags: c, memory-leaks, asprintf

Note: I did call this function and free it main but valgrind still shows error.
This code basically takes in a singly linked-list with two data coeff and exp. This is basically converting a polynomial store in a linked list converted to readable string. I looking to have it dynamic allocated.

```
char *Poly_to_string(const Polynomial *p)
{
    char *x = malloc(1);
    int size;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if((p->exp != 0) && (p->exp != 1))
        {
            size = asprintf(&x, "%s%dx^%d + ", x, p->coeff, p->exp);
            if (size == -1)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
        }   
        else if(p->exp == 1)
        {
            size = asprintf(&x, "%s%dx + ", x, p->coeff);
            if (size == -1)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        else if(!p->exp)
        {
            size = asprintf(&x, "%s%d + ", x, p->coeff);
            if (size == -1)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    x[strlen(x) - 3] = '\0';
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linux `asprintf()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (bolding mine):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The functions `asprintf()` and `vasprintf()` are analogs of
> `sprintf(3)` and `vsprintf(3)`, except that **they allocate a string
> large enough to hold the output including the terminating null
> byte ('\0'), and return a pointer to it via the first argument.**
> This pointer should be passed to free(3) to release the allocated
> storage when it is no longer needed.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> When successful, these functions return the number of bytes
> printed, just like sprintf(3).  If memory allocation wasn't
> possible, or some other error occurs, these functions will return
> -1, and the contents of `strp` are undefined.

This line is wrong:

```
char *x = malloc(1);
```

It should just be

```
char *x;
```

because if `asprintf()` works, it will overwrite the contents of `x` and cause the memory allocated in `char *x = malloc(1);` to be leaked.

**EDIT**

The looping also needs to be addressed, as you're trying to grow the string:

```
char *Poly_to_string(const Polynomial *p)
{
    // start with an empty string that can be free()'d
    // (if you don't have strdup() use malloc() and strcpy())
    char *x = strdup("");
    int size;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        // save the old malloc()'d value so it can be free()'d
        char *oldValue = x;

        if((p->exp != 0) && (p->exp != 1))
        {
            size = asprintf(&x, "%s%dx^%d + ", x, p->coeff, p->exp);
            if (size == -1)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
        }   
        else if(p->exp == 1)
        {
            size = asprintf(&x, "%s%dx + ", x, p->coeff);
            if (size == -1)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        else if(!p->exp)
        {
            size = asprintf(&x, "%s%d + ", x, p->coeff);
            if (size == -1)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
        }

        // free() the old value
        free(oldValue);
        p = p->next;
    }
    x[strlen(x) - 3] = '\0';
    return x;
}
```

There are other ways to do this without the initial `char *x = strdup("");` but the code then becomes a lot more complex.

Comment: thanks. but the memory leak is still there

Comment: You're also looping over multiple `Polynomial *p` since it's a linked list.  You need to retain a copy of the old pointer in `x` and free it after each iteration.  I missed that on my first look at your code.

Comment: Thank you. Your help solved a couple of my problems. Much appreciated. There is still a couple of leaks, but progress has been made!

Comment: I wondering if the x in between each statement is causing the main leak problems

Comment: I don't see how, but this is just one part of your entire bit of code, I assume.  Valgrind should be telling you where the leaked memory was allocated from.

Comment: I'm sorry it is all gone >.< I've forgot to recompile and was working on a old batch. Your help was greatly appreciated. Also, I definitely gain a better understanding on dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You're not deallocating variable x

Comment: in that regards am i need to free x  after I move the contents to another variable? if so I think that's where I lacking knowledge and wisdom, some advice in that regards would help me